# El include de PHP no reconoce archivo XML

Tags: php, xml, php5

Tengo un proyecto php en una carpeta principal estructurado de la siguiente manera:

- Carpeta contenedora:

  - Carpeta `config`

    - archivo XML `conexion.xml`
  - Carpeta `php`

    - sub-carpeta `bd`

      - Archivo PHP `conexionbd.php`
    - Archivo PHP `consultas.PHP`
  - Archivo HTML `index.html`

**conexion.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<conexion>
<servidor>localhost</servidor>
<usuario>
        <usuario_bd>usuario</usuario_bd>
        <contrasena_bd>contrasena</contrasena_bd>
</usuario>
<bd>nombre_bd</bd>
</conexion>
```

**conexionbd.php**

```
<?php
if (file_exists("../../config/conexion.xml")) {

$archivo_xml= simplexml_load_file("../../config/conexion.xml");

/*Se asigna los valores del archivo XML a las variables PHP*/
$servidor=$archivo_xml->servidor;
$usuario_bd=$archivo_xml->usuario->usuario_bd;
$contrasena_bd=$archivo_xml->usuario->contrasena_bd;
$bd=$archivo_xml->bd;

try{

    $conn= new mysqli($servidor,$usuario_bd,$contrasena_bd,$bd);
    echo "Conectado";
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e;
}


}else{
echo "el archivo no existe";
}

?>
```

Si ejecuto la aplicación hasta aquí el resultado es el siguiente: 
[image: Imagen 1]

**consultas.php**

```
<?php
include("bd/conexionbd.php");
?>
```

A la hora de ejecutar la aplicación aquí me muestra lo siguiente:
[image: Imagen 2]

¿A que se debe que el `include("bd/conexionbd.php")` no detecte el archivo XML y como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: tu carpeta ahí la tienes como bd y en la info pones que se llama conexionBD

Comment: @Sr1871 si esta en la raiz, pero al hacerlo me marca lo siguiente: Warning: include(/bd/conexionbd.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\primerLogin\php\consultas.php on line 2

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/bd/conexionbd.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\primerLogin\php\consultas.php on line 2

Comment: ahí no tienes ninguna carpeta llamada bd

Comment: @Sr1871 la tenía con otro nombre, la ruta que está en el `include` si me permite relacionarla con el otro archivo,pero,no me detecta el archivo del `simplexml_load_file`.

Comment: Si ejecuto el archivo `conexionbd.php` me dice que el archivo XML "Si existe".   Pero si ejecuto el archivo `consultas.php` que tiene el `include` si lee el archivo `conexionbd.php` pero no reconoce el `simplexml_load_file` y es por eso el mensaje de que "el archivo no existe"

Comment: Antes de que resuelvas tu problema quisiera hacerte una pregunta: **¿Sabes lo que podría pasar si alguien escribe esto en el navegador: `primerlogin/config/conexion.xml`?**  ¿No sería mejor tener las credenciales de conexión en un archivo `.ini`?

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracia por el comentario, de hecho me haz respuesto a una duda que venía arrastrando acerca de las credenciales de la base de datos, más o menos me has orientado por dónde buscar. Realmente si había estado pensando en la seguridad de tener un archivo XML que al poner la ruta en un navegador dejaría al descubierto las credenciales.

Comment: Mira por ejemplo [esta forma](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO/blob/master/db.php.ini). Este archivo puede ponerse en una carpeta oculta fuera del root (para que sea innaccesible por URL)  y aunque se acceda a él, no mostrará nada, ese es el sentido de esta línea: `<?php return; ?>` La única forma de mostrar/usar lo que hay debajo de esa línea sería abriendo el archivo directamente, o mediante código de PHP corriendo en el servidor.

Comment: @A.Cedano me puse a ver algunos ejemplos con explicación, y me surge una pregunta, ¿Para poder leer el archivo `.ini` es necesario es necesario poner en el código la URL dónde se encuentra? ¿Y no quedaría expuesto? O de que manera se puede hacer

Comment: Claro, es necesario poner la URL, pero estamos hablando de un archivo PHP que está en el servidor, nadie verá las credenciales a no ser que desde ese archivo tú las imprimas, lo cual, creo, nadie haría en su sano juicio. En cuanto a cómo leerlo, [aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO/blob/e886741782ec5e732324dafa47d6f361862ec322/DbPDO.class.php#L49).

Comment: @A.Cedano Excelente aporte voy a estudiarlo más e implementarlo en los siguientes proyectos. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es de contexto; en el camino en la sentencia de la función `file_exists` en el archivo `conexionbd.php`.

El camino relativo utilizado ahí es válido cuando se navega directamente a ese archivo, pero al navegar a `consultas.php`, el primero se ejecuta indirectamente, o sea que al llegar la secuencia de ejecución a la primera línea de `conexionbd.php`, el camino especificado de manera relativa como colocas en el código `"../../config/conexion.xml"` no es válido, pues en ese momento el válido sería `"../config/conexion.xml"`.

Una solución sería poner este último camino, pero tiene la desventaja que no puedes ejecutarlo directamente (lo cual no debería hacerte falta en tu aplicación de todas formas) y de que solo lo podrá incluir y funcionar correctamente desde un archivo que esté en una posición en tu estructura de carpetas tal que el camino especificado sea válido.

La solución que yo le daría sin variar demasiado el esquema que tienes implementado es utilizar una variable global que debe ser especificada por cada archivo declarando el camino que le corresponde.

**conexionbd.php**

```
<?php
if (file_exists("$PROJECTROOT/config/conexion.xml")) {

$archivo_xml= simplexml_load_file("$PROJECTROOT/config/conexion.xml");

/*Se asigna los valores del archivo XML a las variables PHP*/
$servidor=$archivo_xml->servidor;
$usuario_bd=$archivo_xml->usuario->usuario_bd;
$contrasena_bd=$archivo_xml->usuario->contrasena_bd;
$bd=$archivo_xml->bd;

try{

    $conn= new mysqli($servidor,$usuario_bd,$contrasena_bd,$bd);
    echo "Conectado";
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e;
}    
}else{
echo "el archivo no existe";
}

?>
```

**consultas.php**

```
<?php
  $PROJECTROOT = "../";
  include("bd/conexionbd.php");
?>
```

Comment: a o.k. Quiere decir que en el archivo  `conexionbd.php` si se ejecuta correctamente ya que la ruta relativa la inicia desde el nivel origen y por eso utilizo `.../.../`  utilizando los niveles. Pero en el archivo `consultas.php` al estar solo un nivel arriba solo seria`.../` ?. Si declaro una variable antes del `include` esa variable podrá ser leída desde el archivo `conexion.php`?

Comment: Así es, lo veo como dices @FernyCortez.

Answer (score 0):

> *La solución final es la siguiente (Utilizando todas las respuestas):*

**conexionbd.php**

```
<?php
if (file_exists("../config/conexion.xml")) {

$archivo_xml= simplexml_load_file("../config/conexion.xml");

/*Se asigna los valores del archivo XML a las variables PHP*/
$servidor=$archivo_xml->servidor;
$usuario_bd=$archivo_xml->usuario->usuario_bd;
$contrasena_bd=$archivo_xml->usuario->contrasena_bd;
$bd=$archivo_xml->bd;

try{

    $conn= new mysqli($servidor,$usuario_bd,$contrasena_bd,$bd);
    echo "Conectado";
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e;
}


}else{
echo "el archivo no existe";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez te interese utilizar [vlucas/phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) para guardar los datos de conexión entre otros que utilice tu aplicación. para guardarlos y usarlos de manera segura.