# Problema rutas php

Tags: php, rutas

Buenas, estoy luchando hace un rato con el sistema de rutas de php pero sigo con el mismo problema.
Las clases funcionan correctamente, el problema es cuando desde el controlador llamo a una clase, la ruta de la clase que llamo funciona, pero las rutas que esa clase llama no son encontradas, haber si se entiende mejor con el codigo y el error:

Controlador:

```
    <?php

require_once '../models/DAO/HermandadDAO.php';

$accion = $_REQUEST['accion'];
switch ($accion) {
    case "insertar":
        $dao = new HermandadDAO();
        $values = array(
            "nombre" => $_REQUEST['nombre']
        );
        $dao->insertar($values);
        break;
}
```

Clase hermandad DAO:

```
<?php

require_once '../entities/Hermandad.php';

require_once 'AbstractDAO.php';

class HermandadDAO extends AbstractDAO {

    public function insertar($arrayValues) {
        $values = array(
            Hermandad::NOMBRE => $arrayValues["nombre"]
        );
        return parent::insertar(Hermandad::TABLA, $values);
    }

}
```

Clase AbstractDAO:

```
<?php

require_once '../../database/Conexion.php';

class AbstractDAO {
    private $conexion;
    private $dbHandler;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->conexion = new Conexion();
        $this->dbHandler = $this->conexion->getConexion();
        if (!$this->dbHandler) {
            echo "Error al conectar con la base de datos";
        }
    }

    public function insertar($tabla, $values) {
        $sql = "";
        $sql .= "INSERT INTO " . $tabla;
        $sql .= " (" . implode(",", array_keys($values)) . ") ";
        $sql .= "VALUES ('" . implode("','", array_values($values)) . "');";
        $query = mysqli_query($this->dbHandler, $sql);
        if ($query) {
          return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
    }
}
```

y pues el error dice que la clase hermandadDAO no encuentra la clase Hermandad, pero solo me pasa llamandola desde el controller, cuando la pruebo desde el hermandadDAO si funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estructura del proyecto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar la estructura de archivos/directorios de tu proyecto y dónde se encuentran los ficheros involucrados en el problema? Este problema se parece mucho a [este otro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/52643/250) y también a [éste](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/115234/250) y a [éste](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/46337/250). Revisa esas publicaciones porque tu pregunta puede ser un duplicado de esas (los ficheros pueden ser diferentes, pero el problema de raíz es el mismo).

Comment: Gracias, he editado la publicación agregando la estructura del proyecto. Efectivamente, el problema raiz es el mismo que en esos casos, pero sigo sin terminar de entender la solución que dan.

Comment: Podría ir a la raíz directamente  **/**  , `require_once '/models/entities/Hermandad.php'`;

Answer (score 1):

Desde mi punto de vista lo mejor para no tener estos problemas es definir las rutas de forma cualificada, es decir utilizar rutas completas en lugar de relativas.

Por ejemplo PHP provee `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` para situarnos en la raíz, a partir de ahí podemos definir el reto de la ruta, ejemplo:

```
 include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/directorio/archivo.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Supongamos que estamos trabajando de **folderCreate.php** que esta en la carpeta **mkdir**

**folderCreate.php**
tiene a **createFile.php**
que se incluye: `include '../users/createfile.php';`

Y **createFile.php** incluye un **x** archivo en **haider**.
tendria `include '/haider/x.php';`

como estamos en 
**folderCreate.php** no podremos acceder al archivo que **createFile.php** necesita, debido a su `include '/haider/x.php';`
debido a que **folderCreate.php** esta en **mkdir** e intenta realizar respectiva búsqueda desde ese punto y no le calza la ruta.

**Solución**

Es un tema de orientación de ruta en el código.

Al controlador dale el `require_once '../database/Conexion.php';`

y AbstractDAO que **no**  tenga `require_once '../../database/Conexion.php';`.

Hermandad DAO cámbiale a `require_once './models/entities/Hermandad.php';`

con eso debería funcionar pero no es la manera correcta

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, efectivamente ese es el problema,  recien estoy comenzando con php y esto de las rutas se me fue de las manos, no entiendo ni una de como formar correctamente la ruta.

Comment: agregue una posible solución en mi respuesta. está al final